# Setting VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I am using Centos6.3 and I have configure apache using the [Slicehost](http://articles.slicehost.com/2008/12/12/centos-apache-virtual-hosts-1) tutorial.

My configuration is the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName christabellehotel.com
    ServerAlias www.christabellehotel.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/christabellehotel.com
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/sites/christabellehotel.com/error.log
    CustomLog /home/sites/christabellehotel.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName akteabeach.com
    ServerAlias www.akteabeach.com
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/akteabeach.com
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/sites/akteabeach.com/error.log
    CustomLog /home/sites/akteabeach.com/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName 198.199.125.69
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    DocumentRoot /home/sites/
    LogLevel warn
    ErrorLog /home/sites/error.log
    CustomLog /home/sites/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when I open http://christabellehotel.com/ I cannot see tha virtual host which I configure and which is the following: `http://198.199.125.69/christabellehotel.com`

Helpful information:

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd -S

VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
_default_:443          198.199.125.69 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:74)
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server christabellehotel.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1023)
     port 80 namevhost christabellehotel.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1023)
             alias www.christabellehotel.com
     port 80 namevhost akteabeach.com (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1034)
             alias www.akteabeach.com
     port 80 namevhost 198.199.125.69 (/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:1044)
```

Syntax OK

Comment: I don't really get the problem. I can see the christabelle hotel website at http://chistabellehotel.com

Comment: Typo. Of course I mean http://christabellehotel.com

Comment: @etagenklo I just removed the last virtual host but the problem is that I cannot enter the server by ip address in order to test websites without a domain. But at least the website works..

Comment: Do you have the following in your httpd.conf before the virtualhost definitions? `NameVirtualHost *:80`

Comment: @tdk2fe yes. I have the that.

Comment: You shouldn't, you should have `NameVirtualHost *`, not `*:80`

Answer (score 0):

take the third virtualhost entry, move it to the top, and change the directive to

`<VirtualHost 198.199.125.69:80>`

Comment: Hello mate. It does not work again. Check http://christabellehotel.com/

Comment: can you pastie your conf file?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/jFhVM9Yw

Comment: [Try This](http://pastebin.com/KqWaWWzQ).  Also - be sure to reload the httpd daemon... i've wasted hours before b/c I forgot to do it after I modified the config :)

Comment: Doesn't work. Now the 198.199.125.69 goes to christabellehotel directory.

Answer (score 0):

change `NameVirtualHost *:80` to `NameVirtualHost *`

Comment: Starting httpd: [Wed Apr 10 17:28:14 2013] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Wed Apr 10 17:28:14 2013] [error] VirtualHost *:80 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results
[Wed Apr 10 17:28:14 2013] [error] VirtualHost _default_:443 -- mixing * ports and non-* ports with a NameVirtualHost address is not supported, proceeding with undefined results

Comment: because you have a `_default_` setting. please update your question with your complete VirtualHosts configuration